# How can I handle a endless loop in Lua Extension for PHP?

Tags: php, lua

I use the [Lua Extension](http://php.net/manual/en/book.lua.php) with PHP 7.1. Unfortunately, I did not found a really documentation. Only [this](http://www.laruence.com/lua/). I know already that I can use lua sandbox for restricting the access to lua functions.

But how can i restrict the lua duration time? I want to abort lua parsing after x seconds or after x calculation cycles or x lines of code.

If I parse something like this (endless loop):

```
<?php
try {
    $lua = new Lua();
    $lua->eval("
        while 1 do
            -- something
        end
    ");
} catch (Exception $e) {
    $e->getMessage();
}?>
```

the php script runs forever.

Comment: There wouldn't be an exact time attached to it, but you could create a variable outside the loop, like `count = 0` or something, then increment it every loop. If it goes over a certain value, `break` the loop. You could also look into using a library (like [this](https://github.com/APItools/sandbox.lua)) or at least look at how it's implemented

Comment: thanks for your answer. the lua code will be scripted by the users. I cant handle it directly. the php lua extension dont support coroutines. but coroutines are used by your sandbox.lua soluation. It also did not work. I think I must look into the extension code itself.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to override `while` loops like you want, but you could make your own function (say, `While`) that takes a function and uses the `count` method. Something like

```
local limit = 500

function While( condition, dofunc )
    local count = 0
    repeat
        count = count + 1
        if count > limit then
            print( 'Aborting loop: limit (' .. limit .. ') reached.' )
            break
        end
        dofunc()
        var = condition()
    until not var
end
```

And some example usage.

```
local i = 1
local tab = { 'a', 's', 'd', 'f' }
While( function() return tab[i] end, function() 
    print( tab[i] )
    i = i + 1
end )
-- Prints 'a', 's', 'd', 'f'

While( function() return true end, function() print( 'test' ) end )
-- Prints 'test' 500 times, then quits
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I don't know what kind of lua code will be uploaded and executed by the users. so, maybe following code are possible: "While( function() return true end, function() while true do print('endless loop') end end )" I can't solve it in lua without coroutine. I think it will work with the php fork extension or a ajax call on a seperat php process and a serverside timeout, but untested and it feels really dirty.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but I do not see the correct answer here.

The correct answer is to use the setCPULimit Lua sandbox function -

```
public LuaSandbox::setCPULimit(float|bool $limit): void
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/luasandbox.setcpulimit.php